# GCM with login system

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm currently implementing GCM into an application with login system. I wanted to send notification to the application based on the user that logged in to the application (one device, multiple user). I go through these processes.

1. Login as "user A"
2. Register GCM (get Registration ID) send to server side
3. Broadcast Notification out to user A
4. Logout un-register
5. Login as "user B"
6. Register GCM (get Registration ID -occasionally get back same registration ID with user A, sometimes return as different registration ID-)
7. GCM push notification to user A (even if the user un-register)

I'm not sure how to let the application identify the user that logged in to the device and push notification to that specific user only. Instead of user B logged in and get user A's notification. Any comments and answers will be highly appreciated! If you need check on specific codes from my project, please do let me know.

Comment: [this](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html) has solution at the end for registration and unregistration. its late reply but might help someone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The registration ID identifies a specific application on a specific device. It has no knowledge on log-in of users within your application. Therefore, when you un-register GCM (when user logs out), you should call your server to let it know that the user logged out.

This will let your server know that this user is logged out, and the server will stop sending GCM messages to it.

It doesn't matter if you get the same registration ID after user A logs out and user B logs in (even if you get a new registration ID, the old one may still work. That's why GCM returns a canonical registration ID when the device has more than one registration ID for the application).

EDIT :

Lets consider the special scenario (which should be relatively rare) where user A logs out after your server sent it a notification but the notification gets delivered by Google to your application only after user B logs in. The safest way to handle this case is to receive the notification in your application and discard it, showing nothing to user B. In order to know when to discard a received notification you can add a `user` property to your notification data with the user name as its value. When you handle the notification in the app, check that the user property matches the logged in user before displaying the notification.

Comment: I agreed with that. But it might be possible when GCM is pending for example 10 notification to send out to the device and the user is trying to log out from the system. It might be possible that when the user successfully logged out the GCM is yet to send out all the notification. This is my concern so far

Comment: Thank your for the feedback. Based on your edit answer I think I get the idea for it.

Comment: If it's okay with you, I posted another question regarding about GCM as well. Would you mind to take a look?

Comment: @IssacZH. Sure, I answered that question too.

Comment: hi @Eran i have done as you have mentioned i.e  with GCM user data will check the userId and will display/discard  the notification but now if User A logs in after User B then the messages of User A was discarded then how will User A get those discarded notifications.

Comment: @Anitha if you discarded the notification when it came in there would be no way for User A to get the notification later (via the Android system tray). The best you could do would be to persist the notification data before discarding it and have some way of indicating to User A they missed a notification the next time they logged in.

Comment: I suppose actually you could implement a clever solution where before discarding the notification for User A, you send  a request to your server indicating you will discard notification for User A. Then the server could re-send notification next time User A logs in.