# push notification based on users with combination of device and app id in android and iOS devices

Tags: android, ios, cordova, push-notification

We have a existing web site written php and sql.

We are planning to develop a mobile app for the corporate customer which will login to mobile app using there own user id/password.
Whenever a customer achieves any milestone, we need to send a push notification from the php server to mobile apps(android and iOS devices)

I have a question here.

in client module(phonegap with pushplug-in) - which will receive notification from GCM server

as push notification are configured based on device and app id not based on user who have logged.
If different users are using the same device how we need to implement the push notification functionality?
Do the customer need to configure google acount to receive push notification sent from GCM server?(as customer will be logging into the apps with their own credentials)

Please let me know your suggestions or any link which will give some hints on how to achieve this.

Thanks,
Hanmayya

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946586/gcm-with-login-system/15947334#15947334).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your mobile application you will have an class that extents `GCMBaseIntentService` and will override `onRegistered`.

After you application\device is registered against the GCM server, your `onRegistered` method will be called, from this method you will make a call to your web server to register the device, your given the GCM registrationid

```
onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId)
```

The `registrationId` is not device unique and can change when the user remove and reinstalls that app.

For this reason you will want to grab additional information from the device, such as the android ID or better yet, Account information (You will have to request the user permission in your manifest if you want account information)

```
String deviceID = Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

To support all platforms, you might want to check into PushSharp.