# GCM: Send notifications only for the current user logged in application

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

For the application that I am working I need to integrate Google Cloud Messaging. After playing a little with different examples, I was able to send and receive a notification on my deivce.
However, I have come across an interesting situation.  As I know (please correct me if I'm wrong), the registration_id is issued per device and per application.

The application that I'm working supports login functionality. When the application is installed and the user logs in for the first time (let it be "UserA"), I request the registration_id from GCM which then I send it to my server.

Now imagine that UserA logs out and gives his device to some UserB to log in. With other words, UserB logs in using UserA's device.

The problem is that if meanwhile UserA receives a notification, UserB will be able to intercept it. And if UserB receives a notification, he won't be able to receive it.
This seems normal because the registration_id is per device and per application, but it does not seem reasonable for my case.

So I'm asking if there is a way I could make the registration_id to be dependent of some user id (besides the device and app)? Or how could I make such that the logged in user to receive only his own notifications?

Comment: possible duplicate of [GCM with login system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946586/gcm-with-login-system)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes its true that you have one google registration ID for the app per device.

But you can always register and unregister users at your own Server that will actually send messages to GCM and GCM will send this to the registered devices.

Define some interfaces for your Server like registerOnServer and unRegisteronServer , send some unique value for each user on this interface.

So, in your case, when A use Log ins , regitration is done on GCM first and register the user on your Server with registerOnServer inteface and while the user is logged in send notifications pertaining to him to GCM to be send to the device.

When A logs out, unregister him using unRegisterServer and do not send any messages from your Server to GCM as A is unregistered.

So,now if B Logs in even with the same device , register him at your Server and send his messages.

This shall solve your problem!

Comment: This seems like a reasonable solution. However, we have a requirement to let the user log out even when there's no internet connection. This complicates the things a bit, as the Server will think the user is still logged in, and will send the notification.

Comment: You cannot receive notifications if there is no internet connection, so in your app have a broadcast receiver that listens for internet state and the moment internet is available ,check if the user has logged out and unregister him from Server.

Comment: Nice Idea, But please what will happen in a Scenario when User B is logged in to an initial device and now logs in into another Device, Which device is now suppose to receive notification.

Comment: @Nargis How can the server know which devices are actively listening to GCM messages even if the app is in the background?

Comment: @bluejamesbond Devices that are listening to GCM Messages are registered with GCM Server, they will keep listening until unregistered, Background listening, GCMIntentService takes care of that