# Android GCM Different Registration ID

Tags: android, registration, google-cloud-messaging

I'm wondering something about RegistrationID

```
var regid = gcm.register(SenderID);
```

Technically, when register method run, gcm takes SenderID and probably some unique value of my device then creates RegistrationID 
In my scenario,  i've instant messaging app that uses gcm. Now i am getting an account in that app, then gcm sends RegistrationID thats ok. If i wanted to get new account on same device, it does not give new RegistrationID normally.

**How can gcm give diffrent RegistrationID for same application and same device ?**

Comment: Have you read this? http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

Comment: You can't make GCM give you a different RegistrationID for the same app and same device. [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946586/gcm-with-login-system/) how to handle GCM with apps that have login.

Comment: @Eran Thanks, i'm illuminated.

Answer (score 0):

The registration ID is supposed to be unique per app.

Maybe what you need is to add some checks for the signed in user for your app to behave differently when you receive the notification.

for example in `onHandleIntent` method

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
   if(userId==user_id){
     //display notification
   }
}
```